# Android Calendar Showing Wrong Time

Tags: java, android, database, calendar, milliseconds

I have an alarm application and I store alarms into the databse. All alarms work well and the values (miliseconds) are stored as the correct number. Now I'm trying to display those times from my database. And I'm using a Calendar to retreive the time in the Time format :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat timeformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

milis = c.getInt(2);
calendar.setTimeInMillis(milis);
vreme = timeformat.format(calendar.getTime());
listavreme.add(vreme);
```

Milis are retrieved as the right number from the `Cursor` (tested) but when I display the `getTime()` in the HH:mm format it is always displayed with an extra hour. So if the milis value is : 61200000 (17:00), the calendar displays it as 18:00. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to set the TimeZone to you location
try

```
timeformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

for example

Answer (score 1):

Calendar.getInstance() will be tied to a TimeZone. If you don't specifically give it one, it will use the default for the JRE. I guess yours is GMT+1. So, because you are (correctly) saving your raw millis without a timezone, it is losing that hour. Try:

```
    TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(utc);
```

Comment: So it would be best to just save it already tied to a timezone?

Comment: Noooooooo! :)  You are doing it right. Always save dates and times without a timezone. The timezone should just be garnish for the UI - nothing more. Everything stored should be in pure UTC.

Comment: So I just set the timezone when I'm dealing with User? You know what's strange? My timezone is gmt+1, so it is the phones of course but when I put calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));` the same thing happens (time is displayed with 1 hour extra), it only works with GMT, why? I thought I had to set it to my timezone?

Comment: Hmm it only worked when I set the timezone to my format and not the calendar